# Restrict ordering product from different categories in one order

Tags: sql, database-design

Products have different Categories. Clients can only order multiple products from the same category and cannot order products from different categories in the same order. They would need to create a separate order for each category. My issue is I can't figure out how to set this up. See screenshot. The way it's configured now, the Order_Details has the ProductID so there is nothing stopping the client from selecting multiple products from different Categories.

If I put a CategoryID FK in Orders table or Orders_Items table, this would be in violation of the 2nd form of normalization since the Category is an attribute of a product and not of an order. It would also create redundancy since the product category would be in TWO tables.

So would I need to make ANOTHER table for this or is there a way to restrict this by some kind of constraint? (yes, I can restrict this programmatically in my application but I would rather have it set up correctly in the database.

[image]

Comment: Personally I think this kind of stuff are suppose to be completed in your code ... you can check for specialization and add another table, but that's about it, database structure is fine. You are asking to have validation in your database, tables structure won't help you with that. My opinion

Comment: you can share the code, what you have tried to achieve this...

Comment: I haven't used code yet at all. All design was made via the GUI and pen and paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a `CategoryID` in both `Orders` and `Order_Items`, and use composite FK constraints to ensure referential integrity:

```
ALTER TABLE Order_Items
ADD FOREIGN KEY (OrderID, CategoryID)
REFERENCES Orders (OrderID, CategoryID);

ALTER TABLE Order_Items
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ProductID, CategoryID)
REFERENCES Products (ProductID, CategoryID);
```

This will require suitable indexes to be created.

Adding `CategoryID` in the `Orders` table doesn't violate 2NF or 3NF, since it's dependent on the `OrderID` and nothing else. It's not redundant either, since there is no other way to record or derive the functional dependency `OrderID -> CategoryID`.

Adding `CategoryID` in `Order_Items` violates 3NF since it creates a transitive functional dependency (`OrderItemID -> OrderID -> CategoryID` and `OrderItemID -> ProductID -> CategoryID`). However, there is no risk of data anomalies if the FK constraints above are used. Though it introduces redundancy from an informational point of view, it's managed redundancy and it's justified since it's used for referential integrity.

It's possible to achieve the same end without redundancy by using triggers (you would still need the `CategoryID` in `Orders`), but I prefer the simplicity of FK constraints.

Comment: Why not simplify this? Just putting a CategoryID in the Order table, so this way, when a client makes a new order and selects a Category, he will only be displayed with products from that Category. Problem solved, no?

Comment: UI and data model are orthogonal. It's good to present only the relevant options to the user, but without a way of enforcing consistency between the order and ordered products at the DB level, it's possible for invalid data to get recorded, and fixing it is time consuming. Bugs happen and data gets updated in multiple app functions or manually. Enforcing integrity in a single location is simpler and more accurate than the alternatives.